# Using `for` in `range(x)` loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

Shouldn't both blocks of code print similar results? Why is the range function inside of the inner loop reevaluated each time the inner for statement is reached while the range function in the outerloop is only evaluated once?

```
x = 4
for j in range(x)
   for i in range(x)
       print i
       x = 2
```

Results
0
1
2
3
0
1
0
1
0
1

I know the first 4 integers printed ( 0 - 3) are a result of the code
      for j in range(x): code but why are the the following also printed? 
0
1
0
1
0
1
The code

```
x = 4
for j in range(x):
    print i
    x = 5
```

Prints
0
 1
 2 
3

Additional Info
Python 2.7 in IDLE

Comment: Is this really a `practical, answerable question based on actual problems that you face`?  ([faq])

Comment: @codesparkle Why not?

Comment: The code to the right of `in` (the `range(x)` call in this case) is evaluated *each time the loop is entered from above*.  Therefore, the `range` in the outer loop only gets evaluated once, but in the inner loop it gets evaluated for each iteration of the outer loop.  Think of `range` as returning a list, and what that list would hold, each time it is called.  (In python2 it does return a list.  In python3 it's more efficient, and returns a `range` type that's like an iterator.)

Answer (score 4):

Function `range(x)` produces a list of `[0,1,2,3,4]`. In `for` loop you iterate over this list.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
for j in [0,1,2,3]:
    for i in [0,1,2,3]:
        print i
    for i in [0,1]:
        print i
    for i in [0,1]:
        print i
    for i in [0,1]:
        print i
```

Comment: I'm just trying to get a better understanding of how for loop functions work. Can't seem to wrap my head around why the range function in the inner loop is reevaluated while the range function in the outer loops is only evaluated once

Comment: *"range function in the inner loop"* - as you noticed, it is in the inner loop, therefore it will be run in each iteration of the outer loop. What other behavior did you expect?

Comment: I expected the same results if I were to have ran the code <br>

    x = 4
    for j in range(x):
        print j
        x = 5
How come this code only prints 
    0
    1
    2
    3
instead of
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
4

Comment: The `range` function in the outer loop in your example **is** evaluated every time the outer `for` statement is reached. *But that only happens once*. Similarly in your example from the comment with a single loop: `print j` is reached multiple times, but `for j in range(x)` is only reached once.

Comment: The range is evaluated *whenever entering the loop*.  The outer loop is entered once.  The inner loop is entered once per outer loop iteration.

Answer (score 4):

I can only explain by walking through the iterations of the loops, so here goes:

```
x = 4
for j in range(x)
   for i in range(x)
       print i
       x = 2
```

First time through.

```
x = 4
for j in [0, 1, 2, 3]
    for i in range [0, 1, 2, 3]
        print i
        x = 2
```

prints

```
0
1
2
3
```

Now x is set as 2, but the outer loops range has already been executed, so it is not reevaluated.

Code now becomes:

```
for j in [0, 1, 2, 3]:
    for i in [0, 1]:
        print i
        x = 2
```

prints

```
0
1
```

And this continues two more times.

Answer (score 0):

range(x) is evaluated only once i.e. when the loop begins, that is why modifying x inside the loop has no effect.

However, in the first code clock, you change x to 2 in the inner, so the next time the inner loop is executed, range only gives (0,1).

Edit: your first block of code is equivalent to

```
x = 5
for i in range(x)
    print i
    x = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I view it:

Inner loop is executed for each iteration of outer loop

```
x = 4
j = 0
for i in range (x):
    print(i)
    x = 2
j = 1
for i in range(x) # this x is no longer 4 but it is 2
    print(i)
    x = 2
j = 2
for i in range (x): # this x is, of course, 2
    print(i)
    x = 2
j = 3
for i in range (x): # this x is, of course, 2
    print(i)
    x = 2
```

Answer (score -2):

j is not printed, insert " print('xx', j, 'oo') " before " for i in range(x): "

then change to "print('xx', x, 'oo')

or change 'for j in range(x):' to 'for j in range(225,200,-5):' follow with 'print(j)' before 'for i in range(x):'